# Matlab 2012 doesn't run my functions properly

Tags: matlab

I wrote this m-file

```
function adhamm = adhamm(a,b)
    adhamm = a+b
end
```

and when I try to run it via MATLAB's command line by writing

```
a = 2;
b = 3;
adhamm(a,b);
```

I get this error

> Undefined function 'adhamm' for input arguments of type 'double'.

Why is this?

Comment: that doesn't sound right. Try typing `which adhamm`. It is probably not in your path.

Comment: Your code works for me. Are you sure that you didn't forget create a function instead of a script?

Comment: I tried it again and it worked !
that happens many times after , all i did is that i restarted Matlab !

Answer (score 1):

These functions were not placed in the search path for the new version. MATLAB simply does not know where to find them. However, do NOT place them in a MATLAB toolbox directory. That is not the place to put your own functions. Put them in a separate directory that you will tell MATLAB how to find using the path tools. (If you cd to that directory, MATLAB will automatically look there, but that is not a good solution.)

You need to learn about the search path in matlab, and the tools matlab has to maintain search paths. Thus, addpath, savepath, rmpath, pathtool.

Comment: @3mmasr: Or you can put your function into the directory defined n `userpath`.

Answer (score 0):

you saved your function with the name adhamm.m, right? Then try to execute the function within 
the folder of adhamm.m.

Answer (score 0):

You've probably saved a variable with name `adhamm`. Type `clear adhamm` and try again.